# Is 'うつさい' equivalent to 'うるさい' in this context? Why?

Tags: meaning, colloquial-language, gemination

Is 'うつさい' equivalent to 'うるさい' in this context? Why?

I can't find 'うつさい' in the dictionary and Google translate, so I tried inputting the Chinese version of the text(i.e '吵') into Google translate and it told me that it was 'うるさい`

Fri Feb 23 16:47:41 CST 2018 update{
Thank you all,[Google search for 'うっさい'](https://www.google.com/search?newwindow=1&hl=en&source=hp&ei=zdSPWqzCEpLmjwPd3pGoCg&q=%E3%81%86%E3%81%A3%E3%81%95%E3%81%84&oq=%E3%81%86%E3%81%A3%E3%81%95%E3%81%84&gs_l=psy-ab.3...9821.9821.0.10710.1.1.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0....0...1..64.psy-ab..1.0.0....0.MjyLixA54Ys) is working.
}

The whole context : https://www.pixiv.net/member_illust.php?mode=manga&illust_id=66989588
[image]

Comment: It's うっさい, not うつさい.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's 'うっさい' in this context and it's a colloquial style of 'うるさい'.

Comment: Addendum: [う]{u}[っ]{s}[さ]{sa}[い]{i} is a colloquial contraction of [う]{u}[る]{ru}[さ]{sa}[い]{i}, where the _ru_ gets "squished" into the following syllable.  This is similar to the contraction of [分]{wa}[か]{ka}[ら]{ra}[な]{na}[い]{i} into [分]{wa}[か]{ka}[ん]{n}[な]{na}[い]{i}, where the _ra_ gets squished.